# Articles in nominal sentences

Tags: grammar, articles

When one uses nominal sentences (i.e. sentences without a verb, with a subject only), should it be

> Amazing book, I liked it a lot!

or

> **An** amazing book, I liked it a lot!

It's clearly a shortened colloquial variant of "It is/This is an amazing book...," but what about the article if you omit "it/this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are used and understood. These are rather colloquial expressions, we would not use in formal contexts. In informal conversation I would unhesitatingly say

> person x: Just been reading Catch 22.
>
> me: Amazing book. I loved it when I was a teenager

Somehow, the other form seems better for a more rhetorical context, perhaps when writing a review or article, or giving a speech.

> Catch 22; an amazing book. Made quite an impression when I read it as a teenager.